# "request not found" error in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring.I am trying to create a Spring MVC HelloWorld project.There is no error in the code but for some reason when i run it on localhost i am getting "request not found" error.I have rechecked the program but not able to solve the issue.Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

ControllerClass.java (inside src folder)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class ControllerClass {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model){

        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework");        
        return "hello";     
    }
}
```

hello.jsp (inside jsp folder in web-inf )

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml (inside web-inf)

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcexample.xyz" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

 </beans>
```

web.xml (inside lib folder of web-inf)

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>       
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you propertly running a Java Server Pages such Tomcat? Which URL are you accessing to? To me, everything looks fine, so try to find the error out of the box.

Comment: Is the `hello.jsp` located at /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp? Hmmm there are many silly reasons why this does not work....

Comment: Is your `HelloWeb-servlet.xml `referenced in your `web.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your configuration is at the wrong location: by default `HelloWeb-servlet.xml` goes into the root of `WEB-INF` and not inside lib.

If you like to put it somewhere else you need to define a ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml.

Comment: oh sorry.Its in WEB-INF not in lib.I corrected the above code

Answer (score 0):

change the url pattern in your web.xml file to /* instead of *.jsp

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```